# How to do two animations on activity exit in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

How can we do two **animations** on activity exit.

1. Button in Activity
2. Tap the button
3. The button should exit moving upwards and the page should go downwards to show the next activity

[image]

Thanks ..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using transparent activity. Apply this style yo your activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Start your on exit animations and when they will finished just call 'finish()' of your activity.